# Why, intuitively, does a capacitor create current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, capacitance

Suppose we have a planar capacitor connected to a closed wire. If the capacitor is charged, we know that the stored energy will be dumped in the form of current, electrons flowing from the negative side to the positive side. This will happen until all the energy is dumped, which is when the potential difference in the capacitor is nil. This in itself happens when the charge on both plates becomes zero.

The flow happens because of a difference of potential, but it is difficult to imagine what actually happens. Intuitively, one clearly imagines the electrons being attracted through the wire to the positive charge on the opposite plate. However, a defining aspect of a planar capacitor is that the electric field outside is zero. If there is no field along the wire, what exactly moves the current along it?

Comment: *"However, a defining aspect of a planar capacitor is that the electric field outside is zero."* - this isn't true.  Sure, fringing fields are often neglected in determining the capacitance of a planar capacitor but they can't always be neglected without throwing away important physics.

Comment: Only the time derivatives of the fields need to be zero for the usual definition of a capacitor? That's what electrostatic means?

Comment: The field surrounding the capacitor is not the same thing as the field in the wire. On one side of the wire there's positive potential, on the other, negative. So there must be field somewhere inside.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, the field inside the wire clearly isn't due to border effects. Even in ideal capacitors with infinite planes, the difference of potential should still create a current through the wire, and there the field outside the capacitor is zero.

Comment: Steve, for two infinite planes, where is this wire connecting the two planes if it is outside of the capacitor?

Comment: @AlfredCentaur Can you then say that the current is produced strictly because of the border effects?

Comment: Steve, see for example, [this](https://tensortime.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/matter-interactions-ii-week-11/):  *"In chapter 19, we see that traditional textbooks have misled students in a very serious way regarding the behavior of capacitors. Those “other” textbooks neglect fringe fields. Ultimately, and unfortunately, this means that capacitors should not work at all!"*  The textbook referenced is ["Matter and Interactions"](https://books.google.com/books?id=8oyNPd5QbYgC&q=%22fringe+field%22#v=snippet&q=%22fringe%20field%22&f=false)